# "Too many arguments" error

Tags: arduino

I am building a laser that is to be controlled by a joystick. The joystick uses 2 servo motors to move the laser in the direction I want. I am using an arduino board that uses C++ coding.

I get a "too many arguments" error on my outputs.

```
#include <Servo.h>

const int servo1 = 11;       // first servo
const int servo2 = 10;       // second servo
const int joy1 = 5;        // switch 1
const int joy2 = 4;        // switch 2
const int joy3 = 3;        // switch 3
const int joy4 = 2;        // switch 4

int servoVal;           // variable to read the value from the digital pin

Servo myservo1;  // create servo object to control a servo
Servo myservo2;  // create servo object to control a servo



void setup() {

  // Servo  
  myservo1.attach(servo1);  // attaches the servo
  myservo2.attach(servo2);  // attaches the servo

  // Inizialize Serial
  Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop(){

    // Display Joystick values using the serial monitor
    outputJoystick();

    // Read the horizontal joystick value  (value between 0 and 180)
    servoVal = digitalRead(joy1, joy2, joy3, joy4);          
    servoVal = map(servoVal, 0, 45, 135, 180);     // scale it to use it with the servo (result  between 0 and 180)

    myservo2.write(servoVal);                         // sets the servo position according to the scaled value    

    // Read the horizontal joystick value  (value between 0 and 180)
    servoVal = digitalRead(joy1, joy2, joy3, joy4);           
    servoVal = map(servoVal, 0, 45, 135, 180);     // scale it to use it with the servo (result between 0 and 180)

    myservo1.write(servoVal);                           // sets the servo position according to the scaled value

    delay(15);                                       // waits for the servo to get there

}


/**
* Display joystick values
*/
void outputJoystick(){

    Serial.print(digitalRead(joy1, joy2, joy3, joy4));
    Serial.print ("---"); 
    Serial.print(digitalRead(joy1, joy2, joy3, joy4));
    Serial.println ("----------------");
}
```

Comment: Does it not tell you what code the error is related to?

Comment: As yous stated you use Arduino. That is not (pure) C++ and certainly not C. So why adding the C tag (only)?

Comment: like i said i dont know much about software. im a hardware guy

Comment: Before you ask a question here, you might want to read the documentation of the library you are using. You clearly have not done so for `digitalRead()`.

Comment: Have you read the documentation of `digitalRead()`? http://labs.arduino.org/DigitalRead

Answer (score 1):

Would the joystick actually give a digital value or should have been an analogRead? Also I'm pretty sure you can only sample one item at a time with the digitalRead.

Comment: its a digital joystick

Comment: so do i need to make 4 seperate out puts for each digitalread

Comment: Yes, `digitalRead` reads one and only one of your digital inputs